# ASP.NET MVC3 Upload a file from a Partial view (and fill the corresponding field in the Model)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, partial-views

I know the subject has already been [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788372/asp-net-mvc-ajax-file-upload-with-partialviews) on SO and elsewhere, but I can't find any answer to my question.


I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC3 project, and I'd like to create a *Partial view* containing a `FileUpload`. This partial view is called on a basic `Create` page, and I'd like the file to upload belongs to the model to create. It is only when the user will submit the form the selected file will be uploaded.

Here is an explanation by the code :

**Model `ModelToCreate`**

```
public class ModelToCreate
{
    //Some properties

    public FileUploadModel Files { get; set; }
}
```

**Model `FileUploadModel`**

```
public class FileUploadModel
{
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }
}
```

**My PartialView (_UploadFiles.cshtml)**

```
@model Models.ModelToCreate

//I tried with Html.BeginForm(Create, MyController instead of null, null, but with no result.
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Files, new { type = "file", name = "Files" })
}
```

**How the partial view is called (by Create.cshtml)**

```
@Html.Partial("_UploadFiles")
```

I also tried with `@Html.Partial("_UploadFiles", Model)`, but with no result...


When I click the `Submit` button in `Create.cshtml`, the form is submitted to my controller BUT `Files` field is always `null` whereas the other datas are OK.


Am I missing something ? Could you indicate my where (and why ?)
Thank you !

**UPDATE (and Solution)**

Here is some additionnal information I forgot about `Create.cshtml`
The form look like this :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "target-form" }))
{
    // Some fields, Textboxes and others CheckBoxes

    //Call to partial View
}
```

When I take a look to generated source code, I see the partial view in a `<form>` tag... So I have a `<tag>` in a `<tag>`, which is illegal and "ignored". This causes the problem

**SOLUTION** Just add this tag to the BeginForm of `Create.cshtml` :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "target-form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

and call my Partial View as

```
@Html.Partial("_UploadFiles", Model)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this will get it working for you.

`Create.cshtml` View (With the form & submit moved outside of the partial)

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   @Html.Partial("_UploadFiles", Model)
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

`_UploadFiles.cshtml` view

```
@model ModelToCreate

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Files.Files, new { type = "file", name = "Files" })
```

Models (Changed to a List and also note the initializer in the `FileUploadModel` constructor).

```
public class ModelToCreate
{
    //Some properties
    public FileUploadModel Files { get; set; }
}

public class FileUploadModel
{
   public FileUploadModel()
   {
        Files = new List<HttpPostedFileBase>();
   }

   public List<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Controller actions:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new ModelToCreate();

    return View(model);

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ModelToCreate model)
{
   var file = model.Files.Files[0];
   return View(model);
}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with your solution is that your `Create.cshtml` has a `@model FileUploadModel`. But my `Create.cshtml` already has a `@model ModelToCreate` (and this `ModelToCreate` contains this famous `FileUploadModel`. So how can I achieve your result using my `@model ModelToCreate` ? BTW, you have a submit button in your partial view, and I like to upload the files when the user submit the whole form. Thanks again :)

Comment: Sorry that was an error, I've updated that now to be the correct model I think. Give that a whirl and let me know. :)

Comment: Just seen your note about submitting the form outside of the Form, are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: You can simply take the form out of the partial and put it into your create view and it will work as is.

Comment: Ok, this is almost perfect. When I submit the form, `Files` is no longer `null`, but it is empty. Please see http://i.stack.imgur.com/aTnyk.png. And yes, I'd like the user only have one click to submit the form (and the associated pictures).Is there any problem (performance, security...) with this idea ? Moreover, I chose a partial View because I will need the same view in `Update` view, so I thought a Partial View should be the better idea... Do you advice me to avoid partial view ? (it could be easier for me, you're right, but it's a personal project so I try to take it as clean as possible)

Comment: The partial view will have some other fields in the future, this is why I was creating a Partial. I tried your last solution and `Files` is still `null` when I click the button to validate the form, I don't understand why MVC doesn't match this property. This is annoying. However, I upvoted your answer for your help :)

Comment: More fields that makes sense now. That's puzzling why the fields are null when it works for me. Is your form more complicated than what you have posted?

Comment: Sorry if didn't explain very well in my first message. The form is not really complicated, only a dozen of fields the user has to fill in. I'm now trying to add this `Files` field, containg the picture the user can upload (and the pictureS in the future). As a matter of fact, I copy/pasta your solution in another project and I get the same result than you. So we're not far from the solution, but I'd really like only one click to submit the whole form AND the picture(s).

Comment: I just edit my question with the answer I found. I'm sorry, I didn't explain everything and you can't guess what I've done. So, I accept your answer. Thank you for pointing me out the way !

Comment: Oh right, I see what was wrong now. Thanks for the accept. Good luck with the rest. :)